# Parity of number of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, computational-number-theory

In https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3956 is it shown there is a $c>0$ such that $\pi(x)\bmod2$ can be computed in $o(x^{\frac12})$ time (more precisely number of primes $\bmod 2$ for an interval of length at most $O(x^{\frac12+c})$ in $[x,2x]$ can be computed in time $O(x^{\frac12-c})$)?

> If so is there a good estimate known for $c$ and is $\frac12-c=o(1)$ believed achievable?

We know that Cramer's conjecture detects primes in $[x,2x]$ in $P$.

> Assuming Cramer's or Riemann's conjecture is $\frac12-c=o(1)$ believed achievable for $\pi(x)\bmod2$?

Comment: I believe this is not actually established (the paper discusses possible strategies for achieving $c \ge 0$) and all that is proven is the bound $O(x^{\frac{1}{2}+o(1)})$.  (And this isn't enough to deterministically find a prime in $O(x^{\frac{1}{2}+o(1)})$ time since we still have to guess a number with odd parity.  To my knowledge these problems are still open.)

Comment: Theorem 1.2 says something close to this, but the length of the interval is restricted.

Comment: where do you read $c>0$ is not achieved for parity?

Comment: It says ' While this strategy has not been fully implemented, it can be used to establish partial results'and continues  'it can be used to establish partial results, such as being able to determine the \emph{parity} of the number of primes in a given interval in [N,2N] in time O(N1/2−c)'.

Comment: are there other arithmetic functions parity is computable?

Comment: the parity of the number of divisors $d(n) = \sigma_0(n)$ is very easy to compute [cf. "locker problem"] and to sum over an interval :-)

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensFunction.html has some algorithms with similar runtime but I don't know about parity.

Comment: @DanBrumleve you said $c>0$ is not achieved though. Am I interpreting incorrectly?

Comment: I think your more precise statement is correct.  Note the restriction on the interval length, we'd have to call the algorithm $\sqrt{x}$ times to get $\pi{(2 \cdot x)} - \pi{(x)} ~\text{mod}~ 2$. You are also welcome to correspond with me about finding primes over email, it is one of my favorite problems.

Comment: @danbrumleve I do not know more than what the paper talks about for parity. Both CC and parity should put prime finding in P and if CC is needed to get parity then the whole approach in the paper is mute and that is one of my motivations.

Comment: CC would put prime finding in P, but all we get hope to get from parity is a better exponential algorithm (the "square root barrier"), or maybe a subexponential one if the exponent can be made $o(1)$.

Comment: CC does help us _find_ an interval containing an odd number of primes in polynomial time but I can't think of what else.

Comment: You are emphasizing my point with cc providing ability to find an interval of odd parity in poly time. $\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}$ is also $o(1)$ and so we cannot rule out poly time prime finding algorithm with parity of parity count (however if getter parity in poly time itself needs cc the point is mute).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70748/discussion-between-dan-brumleve-and-turbo).

Comment: Should be with parity count.